# how to display thai year (buddha year) in datepicker (sencha extjs 7.5.1)?

Tags: extjs, extjs7

How to display Thai year (buddha year) in datepicker of Sencha Extjs 7.5.1 ?
Example : "2019-01-31" in Thai year is "2562-01-31"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by native sencha components.

You can implement new field with external library like https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/buddhist-era